# How do I allow my pickerView to be dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

From the first screen, the user inputs some numbers pertaining to an Index for an array in the second screen. I transfer the index integer through a basic prepareforsegue override. However, now I am stuck at how I can define the class for the second viewcontroller so I can use the relevant array as the viewPickerDataSource.

For example, I thought this would work:

```
class ChooseColorViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var pickerDataSource: [[String]] = [['orange', 'yellow' 'red'], ['blue', 'cyan', 'sky blue'], ['red', 'magenta','purple']]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.modelViewPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.modelViewPicker.delegate = self;

    testLabel.text = DataPassed
    println(DataPassed)
    //This tests to see if the index got transferred over... it did indeed.

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
var DataPassed:Int!

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource[DataPassed].count;
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerDataSource[DataPassed][row]
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var modelViewPicker: UIPickerView!
}
```

As you can infer from the code, I essentially have an integer 0-2 passed into the current ViewController. I defined a multi-dimensionaly array hoping that if I do pickerDataSrouce[Index], it would create the appropriate pickerView source for me. However, the script crashes before the screen loads, and the debug goes straight to the pickerDataSource[secondDataPassed]. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you are using `DataPassed` but in the other methods you are using `secondDataPassed`.  Which should it be?

Comment: Okay, so it should just be the same variable DataPassed. Got nothing still though.

Comment: Check that `self.pickerView` isn't null in `viewDidLoad` - I think you will find that it is.  You can assign the delegate and datasource directly in your Storyboard, otherwise do it in `viewWillAppear`